# Stats not showing the same values as the Site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I get less values in the api method that in the site, is this posible?

Example: form the API I get that SO has 709980  questions from site 701005

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're saying here, could you edit an example in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question counts on the site are cached.  They don't update realtime, so they will always be behind live numbers

Answer (score 3):

I see that api/stats is a little ahead of the question count:

```
api: 710,258
site (logged in): 710,250
site: (not logged in): 703,405
```

This makes sense to me, none of those counts is completely live, I assume they are cached and regenerated only every so often (every 10 minutes?), to reduce server load. If the api and the site front page are not generated at the same time, then there will always be a small difference between them, with the api or the site higher depending on which one re-gened most recently.