# Get the Time of the Stats and if Possible the new time it will be updated

Tags: feature-request

From [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/505/stats-not-showing-the-same-values-as-the-site) I learned that the stats are cache. I understand the reason for this, so I ask if possible to have the timestamp of the stats return in the api and if possible to have the next time there will be updated or to know the interval.

This way I can not call the api all the time to get the same data.